# How to have subscription resolve a union type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I have a mutation that returns a **Union Type**.

```
  union Task = PersonalTask | OtherTask
  mutation updateTask(...) : Task
  subscription onUpdatePersonalTask(id: ID): PersonalTask
    @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["updateTask"])
```

But this gives an error due to type mismatch in mutation (return is `Task` which is a union) and subscription (returns `PersonalTask`)

**Questions**

1. How to have subscription resolve the mutation union type to a specific type?
2. Is there a cleaner way for subscription to have an auto type resolution?

Answer (score 1):

This may just be a limitation of the directive's implementation. From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/real-time-data.html):

> The return type of a subscription field in your schema must match the return type of the corresponding mutation field.

Assuming there's some kind of `type` field that you're using to distinguish between a `PersonalTask` and an `OtherTask`, one workaround would be to subscribe to all tasks, but use an argument to narrow down the subscription:

subscription onUpdateTask(type: String!): Task
    @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["updateTask"])